# Using QProcess or QDesktopService to open excel sheets

Tags: c++, qt, qprocess

I want to write a programm that opens a file with the standard application of the System (only for windows I think) and closes itseft if the process in which the file is opened is closed.

QDesktopServices::openUrl can be used to open a test.xls file with the correct application but does not give me any feedback about the process.

QProcess gives me full control over the process but can not find the stardard app. Is there a way to open .xls (etc) files with QProcess?

I read somewhere that you can use cmd.exe and the start command as argument to start the process. Is this a good way?

I hope my question is clear.

Comment: In Windows you can launch following command with `QProcess`: `START /WAIT "My File.xls"`. Not sure that it is a cross-platform solution, but haven't seen better ways yet.

Comment: Why do you need the feedback?